# How to Run a Panel Regression?

Tags: python, regression, panel

I am asking for help with running a panel regression
This is my code below

#first import pandas, this is necessary to import data

```
import pandas as pd
```

#second import the data

```
df=pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\Action\Downloads\data.xlsx",8)
```

#import matplotlib so that you can draw graphs

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

#this is to install statsmodels

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
```

#this is to set up the exogenous/ independent variables

```
exog_vars = ["GDP", 'WTI']
exog = sm.add_constant(df[exog_vars])
```

#this is to view the data

```
print(exog.head(7))
```

#set the endogenous/dependent variable

```
endog = df['debt']
```

#you must have linearmodels pip installed
#pip install linearmodels

#this is to import linearmodels

```
import linearmodels
```

#this is to import the PooledOLS and PanelOLS commands

```
from linearmodels.panel import PooledOLS
from linearmodels import PanelOLS
```

#this is where the model is run

```
mod = PooledOLS(df['debt'], exog)
pooled_res = mod.fit()
print(pooled_res)
```

I am receiving an error from the code mod = PooledOLS(df['debt'], exog)

The error is
ValueError: Series can only be used with a 2-level MultiIndex

Does anyone know how to fix the problem?

Comment: The error occurs when your endogenous/dependent variable does not include the right 2-level multiindex with panel variables, so your dataframe is probably not constructed with the right index. Please [edit] your question to show `df.head()` and `df['debt'].head()` and provide information on the variables that you intend to use for the panel structure (unit and time identifiers).

Comment: Ok, what do you mean by right 2-level multiindex with panel variables?

Comment: I can send you the script file, and the data to see if you are interested?

Comment: The index of the dataframe needs to have two levels, containing the two variables you intend to use to define the panel structure of the dataset. Run `df.head().to_dict(orient='index')` in your code and add the output to your post. And repeating the above request, identify the variables you intend to use as the unit and time identifiers for the panel.  All relevant information needs to be included in the post.